# SharePoint Page in Power BI Report not Display

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

PBI reports into SharePoint pages for staff to access. All staff has O365 licenses, which should include the ability to view the embedded reports, and they have access to the respective SharePoint site and page. But they See

Like this [image: Error in SharePoint Page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding a report in SharePoint doesn't remove the requirement for the user to have a Power BI Pro license or use a Premium capacity.

> Licensing
>
> To view the embedded report, users need either a Power BI
> Pro or Premium Per User (PPU) license or the content needs to be in a
> workspace that's in a Power BI Premium capacity (EM or P SKU).

[Embed a report in a secure portal or website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-embed-secure#licensing)